# Volley GET Requests in Fragments error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

The application has three sliding tabs ([Tab1](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/RepertoireTab.java#L27),[Tab2](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/SoonTab.java#L27),[Tab3](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/ArchiveTab.java#L27)) called in the [MainActivity](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/MainActivity.java#L15) in every fragment I'm making a different HTTP GET request, and I'm updating the [Adapter](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/adapters/KinoAdapter.java#L17). The [first fragments's layout](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/repertoire_layout.xml) is updating with the [second HTTP GET request](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/SoonTab.java#L54), and Im not getting anything on the other two layouts. It worked fine when I only called one request(on a different [project](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoApplication)).
  I tried I tried adding two more adapters with three different layouts, but it didnt work, I tried changing the StringRequest's [name](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/empire/kinonewapplication/SoonTab.java#L54) on every tab, that didn't work either. I read something about synchronous and asynchronous requests on Volley, I think Synchronous request is the way to go, but I don't know how to implement it with Volley. You can have a look at the application over [here](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication), and if anyone had some experience with this library, please give me some pointers.

Comment: show your code @kinsell

Comment: I provided some links in the question, to specific parts of the entire code.

Comment: Do you need me guys to update the question with codes and not links ?

Comment: ...your code seems fine...we need to do some trick to find the exact issue

Comment: I did this using AsyncTask on every request and it worked fine. updating the right layout at the right time. but the was very slow. some suggested that i can use the Volley library, and thats how i got  here. Any trick is welcomed sir

Comment: see...volley internally also works same as AsyncTask do...but volley is advanced in many case..like it internally manages the requestquest..support caches..etc...so thats not the case..

Comment: Do you have any suggestions @AngadTiwari

Comment: Okay this is going to sound weird, but I had some weirder stuff before. Try changing the name of the request object. So that they're not both with the same name.

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo nope still giving the same result..

Comment: @kinsell too bad, could you also try with what's in the response listener? just add something unique to your log for example.

Comment: ok, this is gonna sound weird. I tried commenting out the SECOND and the THIRD request. result : not getting any data for the first layout. Tried commenting out FIRST and SECOND request. same result as the first one, not getting anything on the third layout. but when I tried commenting out the FIRST and THIRD request. result : i was getting the data from the second request but on the first layout, it was blank on the second. again you can see my entire code over [here](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoNewApplication), maybe I missed something, somewhere else

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo I tried with the log,when the app starts, two request are made after that when i tried sliding from on to another tab, more requests are made BUT they are filling out wrong layouts

Comment: @kinsell I'll look into it when I have the time, in the meantime I'm suspecting it has something to do with volley cannot figure out the differences.

Comment: ok @KevinvanMierlo ill try switching from fragments to activities now, and completely transform my UI. maybe thats the problem..

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo  update: I tried using activities instead, and it worked. It was getting the right data on the right layout. But this is not a solution to my problem, I don't want to change my entire UI.

Answer (score 0):

Because I extended ListFragment i had to use `listView = getListView();` That was the problem.

Comment: Glad you solved it! I was just forking the repository to see what was wrong

Comment: after 6 long days. its a nice feeling. thank you though @KevinvanMierlo